# Dynamic input hidden field disappears

Tags: jquery, html, arrays, css

I have been trying to multiple the price with the integer and trying to save it in the hidden field which would get the value from hidden field then again multiple it but the hidden field disappears after second click here is my code below.

```
function AddDeductPrice(x,y)
    {

        var z = $("#qty" + y).val();
        if (z > 0) {
            if (x == 0) {
                //i++;
                var l = document.getElementById('qty' + y).value;
                l++;
                $("#qty" + y).val(l);

                var j = document.getElementById('qty' + y).value;

                //var price = document.getElementById('PID' + y).value;
                var price = $("#PID" + y).val();
                alert(price);

                var MultiplyPrice = parseInt(j) * parseInt(price);

                alert(MultiplyPrice);

                $("#PID" + y).val(MultiplyPrice);
                //document.getElementById('PID' + y).value = MultiplyPrice;
                $("#priceID" + y).text(MultiplyPrice);

            }
            else {
                var y = $("#qty").val();
                if (z != 1) {
                    y--;
                    $("#qty").val(y);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

This is of javascript and Jquery and the other code is the HTML below

```
@if (Model.objlist1.Count > 0)
                {
                    int i = 0;
                    foreach (var item in Model.objlist1)
                    {
                        i++;
                        <tr>
                            <td><img src="~/imgProd/@item.image1" class="img-responsive img-rounded img-thumbnail"></td>
                            <td>
                                <h6>@item.product</h6>
                                <p>Gift options also available.</p>
                            </td>
                            <td><span>By @item.deliverydate</span></td>
                            <td>
                                <input type="text" name="qty" id="qty@(i)" maxlength="12" value="1" title="Qty" class="input-text qty form-control" disabled>
                                <div><p class="up" id="upid" onclick="AddDeductPrice(0, '@(i)');">+</p><p class="dn" id="dwnid" onclick="AddDeductPrice(1, '@(i)');">-</p></div>
                            </td>
                            <td id="priceID@(i)"><input type="text" value="@item.price" id="PID@(i)" style="visibility:hidden">₹ @item.price</td>
                            <td> <i class="fa fa-close span03"></i></td>
                            <td><a href=""><i class="fa fa-heart"></i> Move to Wishlist</a></td>
                        </tr>
                    }
                }
```

whether i use hidden or use style to hide the input after second click it hides the input when i use F12 in chrome.
var price is empty on second which shows NaN but on first it shows value.

Comment: could you make a fiddle?

Answer (score 0):

Problem here is at `$("#priceID" + y).text(MultiplyPrice);` line of `AddDeductPrice()`.

It will remove the `input` inside the `<td id="priceID@(i)"></td>`.

Instead use as below:

```
$("#priceID" + y).html($("#priceID" + y).html().replace($("#priceID" + y).text(), MultiplyPrice));
```